# `eksctl delete cluster` `cannot delete orphan ELB Security Groups` resource has a dependent object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, eksctl

```
eksctl delete cluster --region=us-west-2 --name=myeks-2

[ℹ]  using region us-west-2
[ℹ]  deleting EKS cluster "myeks-2"
[ℹ]  cleaning up LoadBalancer services
[✖]  cannot delete orphan ELB Security Groups: cannot delete security group k8s-elb-aaa: DependencyViolation: resource sg-yyy has a dependent object
```

I created an EKS cluster, I helm installed a few things, now I want to blow it away, and recreate, and try again. It seems there is an orphan ENI + SG that can't be deleted and I can't understand why.

`aws ec2 delete-security-group --group-id "sg-yyy"`

> An error occurred (DependencyViolation) when calling the DeleteSecurityGroup operation: resource sg-yyy has a dependent object

I can find one network interface referencing this security group with:

```sh
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --filters Name=group-id,Values=sg-yyy | jq '.NetworkInterfaces[].NetworkInterfaceId'
```

If I try to delete that, I get

`aws ec2 delete-network-interface --network-interface-id eni-xxx`

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the DeleteNetworkInterface operation: Network interface 'eni-xxx' is currently in use.

If I do:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances > instances.json
aws ec2 describe-nat-gateways > nat-gateways.json
aws ec2 describe-network-acls > network-acls.json
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces > network-interfaces.json
aws ec2 describe-security-groups > security-groups.json
```

and then `grep eni-xxx *.json` and `grep sg-yyy *.json`, I get three results: the two entity results themselves and one reference from eni-xxx to sg-yyy. No EC2 instances are referencing either... I'm not sure how to fix this.

FYI, I've not done any custom AWS stuff with this EKS cluster. No custom networking or AWS commands. I was just hoping to create and delete/recreate test clusters and am trying to resolve this blocking error.

Answer (score 1):

the solution was to manually delete the ELB using the security group:

```sh
aws elb describe-load-balancers | jq '.LoadBalancerDescriptions[] | select (.SecurityGroups[] | contains("sg-yyy")) | .LoadBalancerName'

aws elb delete-load-balancer --load-balancer-name <load-balancer-name>
```